# Flex box in react Native is not working buttons wont show up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flexbox, react-props

I have a problem with flex styles.

#### Scenario

- If I put `flex: 1` line in my code, the buttons won't show up
- If I delete `flex: 1` they show up.

Please help me! It's in the new React Native 0.61 I did delete flex but I need it.

How can I fix it? Or is share a bug in 0.61 ...

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

import Header from './Components/Header';
import StartGameScreen from './screens/StartGameScreen'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View styles={styles.screen}>
      <Header title="Geuss a Number"/>
      <StartGameScreen/>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
  }
});
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';

const StartGameScreen = props => {
  return(
      <View style={styles.screen1}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Start a New Game!</Text>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <Text>Select a Number</Text>
            <TextInput />
            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
              <Button title="Reset" />
              <Button title="Confirm" onPress={() => {}} />
            </View>
        </View>
      </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen1: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    marginVertical: 10
  },
  inputContainer: {
    width: 300,
    maxWidth: '80%',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingHorizontal: 15
  }
});

export default StartGameScreen;
```

StartGameScreen.js

[image]

> Photo 1: flex: 1 code in my StartGameScreen.js

[image]

> Photo 2: by deleting flex: 1 code in my StartGameScreen.js the buttons shows

But I need my flex what am I doing wrong? Sorry for my poor post at the beginning its my first post !

Comment: you shoud give a image what effect you want?

Comment: What is `wrong` place for you? I can't see it with no screenshot, no explanation. Maybe you just need to understand the limits of each box. Please provide an example using `codesandbox`. I created a clean app for you here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-ulkom

Comment: @Nick. I use your code, but the effect is correct. you can see this(https://snack.expo.io/@rns/bold-celery)

Comment: give an exact explanation for which `flex:1` you delete

Comment: I did edit the post with a better description of my problem and 2 images Its my first time using stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding flex: 1 to inputContainer and to buttonContainer flex: 1 as well

Comment: I tried: Not working In the front of App.js I have flex: 1 for (Header). and in StartGameScreen.js if I delete all the flex: 1 It will show my buttons but I need it ...

Comment: try to remove all width values, maxvalues etc from all your styling, just go to flex: 1 in everything and build it up from there. Its hard to know whats causing the issue, because we dont know where you are deleting flex:1. Also i am not big fan of the fixed width: 300. Try to set values like dynamicly based on width of the screen.

Comment: Sorry @CosmicSeizure It's my first post First time using StackOverflow so I edit my post!

Comment: CosmicSeizure Thank you! I found the problem at App.js <View styles={styles.screen}> misspelled View styles need to be style